# Getting a select input to have appropriate option selected on form load?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have a form that allows the user to edit information about a location. There's a select input allowing the user to enter the location's category. I'm using Express + EJS to access the existing info in the database. When a user chooses to edit a location's info - I want the select input to have the appropriate category selected when the form loads. Here's the way I have things set up at the moment:

Route:

```
app.get("/locations/:id/edit", function(req, res){
  res.render("locations/edit", {location: req.location});
});
```

Form:

```
<select id="category" name="location[category]">
  <option value="Lake" <% if (location.category == "Lake") { 
  %>selected<% } %>>Lake</option>
  <option value="Beach" <% if (location.category == "Beach") { 
  %>selected<% } %>>Beach</option>
  <option value="River" <% if (location.category == "River") { 
  %>selected<% } %>>River</option>
</select>
```

This is what came to mind. Surely there's a better way to achieve this without having an if statement for EVERY option. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many categories are there. What do you want to do if the item does not belong in lake, river, beach?

Comment: Wait i missed the question. Writing answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will work. Give it a try and let me know. Thanks.

```
<select id="category" name="location[category]"><%
let opts = [ 'Lake', 'River', 'Beach'];
for(let opt of opts){

 %><option value="<% opt %>" <% if (location.category == opt) { %>selected<% } %> > <% opt %></option><%

}
%></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

What i am doing some times is using a script tag

```
<select id="category" name="location[category]">
<option value="Lake" >Lake</option>
<option value="..." >Lake</option>
</select>
<script>document.getElementById("category").value='<%- location.category %>'</script>
```

I also think UR missing the <%- or <%=, could be something changed with the time in EJS